# good ways to convert xhtml to json?

Tags: html, json, xhtml

Are there any good ways of converting xhtml to json? I couldn't find any existing scripts to do that, so I'm not sure if the best way is to somehow write a script to parse the xhtml, convert it to some other format and then to json.

Answer (score -1):

I've found [XML to JSON](http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.WQo3KlPyvaY) converters and [HTML to JSON](http://www.freecodeformat.com/html-json.php) converters online with a few Google searches. You may be able to use these together to convert XHTML to JSON, or you could spend a few minutes Googling and you may find an alternative.